# Phpword code removes backslash and characters

Tags: php, phpword

I've got an issue with phpword, hoping somebody can clarify this.

Im using template processor and clone block to add a file path to a document.

One of the file path's used as an example now(stored in MySQL) is media\154512088747.jpg. However, once phpword inserts it, it gets inserted as media4512088747.jpg. so it actually removes the backslash and following 2 characters.
Please can somebody shed some light on this...to note, that this problem only occurs inside the cloneblock section. I am inserting file paths elsewhere in the document - outside of the cloneblock and it gives me no hassles at all.

Comment: I've noticed aswell, that if i type media\154512088747.jpg in inverted commas in sublime text. Sublime text highlights the characters that's getting removed, so the backslash obviously means something.

Comment: Please show us a minimal example of the problem as a code snippet. Any number of problems could be causing this. For example, testing this in PHP 7.0.14, executing `echo "media\154512088747.jpg"` will produce `medial512088747.jpg`, as the `\154` is being converted into `l` due to a difference in how PHP treats double quotes vs. single quotes.

Comment: echo $rttc =  $row1['right_trailer_tyre_condition']; //inserting  / searching / inserting values $templateProcessor->setValue("right_trailer_tyre_condition", $rttc);